# How to generate contract and esignature by Docsign API?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am not able to find the proper way to integrate Docsign contract and esignature API.
I need document refrence and example in php to interate these API's in my website.

Official document in clear for me, so if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: You'll need to explain more specific what kind of "integration" you want to achieve, and what step you are stuck on exactly in the documentation. At the moment we don't really know how to help you specifically. If you have any existing code as part of your efforts to build the integration, you should show us that too. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP code to do that, it's also in [GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/EmbeddedSigningService.php):

However, to make sure you are successful right away, I suggest you use our [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to download PHP code that is configured for you with all the authentication related configuration.

PHP Code:

```
public static function make_envelope(array $args, string $demoPath, string $pdfFile): EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        # document 1 (pdf) has tag /sn1/
        #
        # The envelope has one recipient.
        # recipient 1 - signer
        #
        # Read the file
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demoPath . $pdfFile);
        $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);

        # Create the document model
        $document = new Document(
            [ # create the DocuSign document object
                'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
                'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
                'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
                'document_id' => 1 # a label used to reference the doc
            ]
        );

        # Create the signer recipient model
        $signer = new Signer(
            [ # The signer
                'email' => $args['signer_email'],
                'name' => $args['signer_name'],
                'recipient_id' => "1",
                'routing_order' => "1",
                # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
                'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
            ]
        );

        # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
        $sign_here = new SignHere(
            [ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
                'anchor_string' => '/sn1/',
                'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
                'anchor_y_offset' => '10',
                'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
            ]
        );

        # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->settabs(new Tabs(['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here]]));

        // Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition(
            [
                'email_subject' => "Please sign this document sent from the PHP SDK",
                'documents' => [$document],
                # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
                'recipients' => new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
                'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
            ]
        );

        return $envelope_definition;
    }
```